# Migrate from ifupdown to netplan

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, netplan, ip-forward

I try to migrate from `ifupdown` to `netplan`, but the result is always not same.

What is the correct `netplan` configuration for `networking` configuration like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno0
iface eno0 inet static
  address xxx.xxx.51.20/24
  gateway xxx.xxx.51.254 
  post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
  post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eno0/proxy_arp


auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
  address xxx.xxx.198.104/24
  bridge-ports none
  bridge-stp off
  bridge-fd 0


auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
  address xxx.xxx.198.105/24
  bridge-ports none
  bridge-stp off
  bridge-fd 0

auto vmbr2
iface vmbr2 inet static
  address xxx.xxx.198.106/24
  bridge-ports none
  bridge-stp off
  bridge-fd 0

auto vmbr3
iface vmbr3 inet static
  address xxx.xxx.198.107/24
  bridge-ports none
  bridge-stp off
  bridge-fd 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of trials and errors, I found out that at the moment, [netplan doesn't support macvlan bridge yet][5], we need a workaround and alter `systemd` network:

- We need to create a few files on `/etc/systemd/network`, so navigate to the directory:

```
$ cd /etc/systemd/network
```

- Define vlans for the bridge, please change `cat` to your editor

```
$ cat 00-vmvlan0.netdev 
[NetDev]
Name=vmvlan0
Kind=macvlan
# Optional MAC address, or other options
MACAddress=xx:xx:xx:xx:26:12

[MACVLAN]
Mode=bridge

$ cat 00-vmvlan0.network 
[Match]
Name=vmvlan0

[Network]
Address=xxx.xxx.198.104/32
IPForward=yes
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes
```

- Define Bridge

```
$ cat 00-vmbr0.netdev 
[NetDev]
Name=vmbr0
Kind=bridge

$ cat 00-vmbr0.network 
[Match]
Name=vmbr0

[Network]
MACVLAN=vmvlan0
```

- repeat for the next IPs
- Link bridge, vlan, and interface:

```
$ cat 10-netplan-eno1.link 
[Match]
MACAddress=xx:xx:xx:xx:19:d0

[Link]
Name=eno1
WakeOnLan=off

$ cat 10-netplan-eno1.network 
[Match]
MACAddress=xx:xx:xx:xx:19:d0
Name=eno1

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
MACVLAN=vmvlan0
MACVLAN=vmvlan1
MACVLAN=vmvlan2
MACVLAN=vmvlan3

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=100
UseMTU=true
```

- and we can use default netplan configuration:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: xx:xx:xx:2a:19:d0
            set-name: eno1
```